# Maps on Android - how to rotate the map monitoring user's heading?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'd like to rotate the maps in my app so they follow the direction the user is heading - pretty much like it can be done on iOS, using the

`[map setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading]`

call. So if a user turns around, the map rotates, showing what's in front of him always on top (like in many FPS games ;)

Is there a simple solution to get this working in Android app (it's API v2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Gather `Locations` from `LocationClient` or deprecated `GoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener`
- create `CameraPosition` with lat/lng from `Location` object, bearing calculated from `SensorManager` and high zoom + tilt
- put into [CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#newCameraPosition%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition%29)
- and the result put into `GoogleMap.animateCamera` with small duration

Comment: the Location's bearing isn't related with device orientation though, but is with device movement, I think (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing()) - so is there a way to read that bearing that changes as I turn around with my phone?

Comment: @kender Oh. You'll have to use some `Sensor` (probably magnetic field) from `SensorManager` or maybe [`SensorManager.getOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float[],%20float[]%29).